# How can I make recursion function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a loan calculator that calculates what percentage of your salary(0.5 = 50 %) you have to save monthly in order to buy a house in 36 months. I wanted to start with 0.5 because it's in the middle,and if portion saved is too high to access high() and if the portion is not enough to access low() until it finds the right amount. In this example it keeps returning the same value( 0.5). How can I make it work?

```
def calculate(portion_saved):

    anual_salary = 300000
    semi_annual_raise = 0.07
    total_cost = 1000000
    portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost
    nr_months = 0
    current_savings = 0

    for x in range(1, 37):
        monthly_salary = anual_salary / 12
        monthly_interest = 0.04 / 12 * current_savings
        current_savings = current_savings + monthly_salary*portion_saved + (current_savings*0.04)/12
        nr_months += 1
        if nr_months % 6 == 0:
            anual_salary = anual_salary + (anual_salary*semi_annual_raise)


    while current_savings + 100.00 != portion_down_payment or current_savings - 100.00 != portion_down_payment:
        if current_savings + 100.00 > portion_down_payment or current_savings - 100.00 > portion_down_payment:
            high(portion_saved)

        else:
            low(portion_saved)

    print(current_savings, portion_down_payment)


def high(portion_saved):
    return portion_saved / 2


def low(portion_saved):

    return portion_saved + (1 - portion_saved) / 2


calculate(0.5)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what is a recursion

Comment: You're calling `high()` and `low()`, and then you're not doing anything with the values they return. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: after I call high(portion_saved) I want the return value to replace the value of portion_saved in the calculate function and start again : calculate(portion_saved) with the new value,untill it finds the exact value of portion saved so current savings +/- 100 = portion_down_payment

Comment: @razvan If you want to replace the value of `portion_saved`, you need to assign the returned value to `portion_saved`. Your loop condition does not depend on the value of `portion_saved` though, so it's either going to run forever or not at all. If you want to recurse, you need to do that - the function does not repeat automatically if you assign a new value to a parameter. (Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.)

Comment: I`m not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer your question.

```
    while current_savings + 100.00 != portion_down_payment or current_savings - 100.00 != portion_down_payment:
        if current_savings + 100.00 > portion_down_payment or current_savings - 100.00 > portion_down_payment:
            calculate(high(portion_saved))

        else:
            calculate(low(portion_saved))
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have another error: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" . It runs in a infinite loop

Comment: It's because of the high and low functions, if the `current_saving` has a value between and not exact 250100 or 290000 it didn't break the loop so it enter the method low() and then high() again ....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to have your `while loop` outside of your `calculate` function. I also changed your `while loop condition` and the `low` and `high` functions, so it converges quickly. You could get inspiration from this :

```
def calculate(portion_saved):

    anual_salary = 300000
    semi_annual_raise = 0.07
    total_cost = 1000000
    portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost
    nr_months = 0
    current_savings = 0

    for x in range(1, 37):
        monthly_salary = anual_salary / 12
        monthly_interest = 0.04 / 12 * current_savings
        current_savings = current_savings + monthly_salary*portion_saved + (current_savings*0.04)/12
        nr_months += 1
        if nr_months % 6 == 0:
            anual_salary = anual_salary + (anual_salary*semi_annual_raise)

    print("portion_saved", portion_saved)
    print("current_savings", current_savings)
    print("portion_down_payment", portion_down_payment)
    print("")
    return current_savings

def high(portion_saved):
    # return portion_saved / 2
    return portion_saved / 1.5

def low(portion_saved):
    return portion_saved * 1.3
    # return portion_saved + (1 - portion_saved) / 2

portion_saved = 0.5
current_savings = calculate(portion_saved)

total_cost = 1000000
portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost

while current_savings > portion_down_payment + 1000.00 or current_savings < portion_down_payment - 1000.00:
    if current_savings > portion_down_payment + 1000.00:
        portion_saved = high(portion_saved)
    else:
        portion_saved = low(portion_saved)
    current_savings = calculate(portion_saved)
```